# How to define polymorphic method and method without parameters in wsdl

Tags: java, wsdl

there are two problems.The first one is,how to define a method without parameters,I wrote the code as follows,but the result was that method had parameter whose type is `Void`.

```
<xsd:complexType name="void">
</xsd:complexType>
```

The second problem is,what can I do to define polymorphic method,there are several method with same name but different parameters.My code is as follows,and It just generate one method whose type of parameter is `List`.

```
<xsd:complexType name="initial">
            <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3">
                    <xsd:element name="initial" type="xsd:string"/>
                 </xsd:sequence>
                 <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                     <xsd:element name="initialInt" type="xsd:int"/>
                 </xsd:sequence>
             </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
```

By the way,I use `Java` language.

Comment: There is no one who knows it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it,we can't declare polymorphic method in wsdl,and we can declare a method without parameters by this way:

```
<xsd:complexType name="initial">
   <xsd:sequence />
</xsd:complexType>
```